# How can I target a variable with string content in a jQuery wrapper?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Basically what I am after is this,

```
var foo = 'I am foo!';
alert(window['foo']);

// output = I am foo!
```

This does not work in a jQuery wrapper, I understand that it may be due to jQuery having renamed the window object or whatnot. If anyone has any inkling as to if this may be possible in a jQuery wrapper, I would appreciate the knowledge !

Comment: Can you show example of code that isn't working?

Comment: I found the problem, as you can see from the comment below. Thank you for your interest !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foo = "I am foo!";
```

If you have a function scope around your `var` line, it'll define it as a local variable instead of a global variable. It's not jQuery "renaming the window object" or anything silly like that, it's just how `var` works. I'd personally doing

```
window.foo = "I am foo!";
// or
window["foo"] = "I am foo!";
```

though, to make it explicit you wanted to define a global variable. Or use a comment to say that.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The idea was I would pull in a string, like, the id of an element such as 'mob', and their would be a variable also called 'mob'. What I wished was to target the variable with the string using the method above.

Comment: @duckbox: And what's preventing you from doing that?

Comment: Ah, I have discovered the error of my ways. I was declaring the var AFTER the document.ready begins. If I place it BEFORE, it works fine. I should really head back to school ! Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 1):

jQuery doesn't rename the window object - jQuery is actually under it (window.jQuery).

Try this:

```
window.foo = 'I am foo!';
alert(window.foo);
```

Answer (score 0):

For non global variables or private variables it's possible to use eval over string expressions;

```
var JohnDoe = function(foo){
  var x;
  eval("x = foo");
  return x;
};

//now we can setup foo values
JohnDoe("MAKUKULA")
=> "MAKUKULA"
```

But it might be pointed out the following:

> This feature is obsolete. Although it may still work in some browsers,
>   its use is discouraged since it could be removed at any time. Try to
>   avoid using it.